# jquery:How do i attach an array to form request and send it to php in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
var subtbl = $(this).attr('data-counter');
                 var stunbr = $(this).attr('data-stunbr');
                var m = 0;
                var checkedlines = new Array();
            $.each($("#sub-table"+subtbl+"  "+"input:checked"),function (m){            
            var chk_value = $("#chk_"+stunbr+"_"+m).attr('value');
                var txt_value = $("#txt_"+stunbr+"_"+m).attr('value');
              //alert("Txt value --->"+ txt_value +" Chk Value --->"+ chk_value);           
            checkedlines[m] = { STUNBR: stunbr, SNO: chk_value, NAME: txt_value }; 
                m++;          
        });
```

How do iattach the "checkedlines" to  form request in jquery and send it to php .I mean do we need to use $.ajax can you show in attaching "checkedlines[]"
Can we produce this array n Json  any method available in Jquery to produce JSON 
How can i consume that in php if it is a plain array .One more thin How do i  Iterate through the  "checkedlines[]" array outside 
of the each loop without using the  "var r=0 "  variable

```
    var r=0;
    $.each(checkedlines,function(r){
        alert("ASNURNNBR==>"+checkedlines[r]['STUNBR']+"SEQNO==>"+checkedlines[r]['SNO']+"RCVDATY==>"+checkedlines[r]['NAME']);
        r++;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to serialize the object into a JSON string and write the result into a hidden field inside of a form the user can submit.

```
<form>

 ...

<input id="json_array" type="hidden" name="json_array" />

 ...

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

function stringify(obj) {
    var t = typeof (obj);
    if (t != "object" || obj === null) {
        // simple data type
        if (t == "string") obj = '"'+obj+'"';
        return String(obj);
    }
    else {
        // recurse array or object
        var n, v, json = [], arr = (obj && obj.constructor == Array);
        for (n in obj) {
            v = obj[n]; t = typeof(v);
            if (t == "string") v = '"'+v+'"';
            else if (t == "object" && v !== null) v = stringify(v);
            json.push((arr ? "" : '"' + n + '":') + String(v));
        }
        return (arr ? "[" : "{") + String(json) + (arr ? "]" : "}");
    }
};

var checkedLines = {};

//
// Your code populating the checkLines object goes here
//

var jsonResult = stringify(checkedlines);

$('#json_array').val(jsonResult);

</script>
```

The **stringify()** function is taken from the [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/js.html) library.

If you don't want to use a form then yes, $.ajax(); is a way to go. Simply add jsonResult to the data property with a relevant variable name:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: 'http://example.com',
  data: "json_array=" + jsonResult,
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

Comment: @Someone: Oops, it was a typo on my part. Give that function a new try.

Comment: @saul: Do i need to download from the JSON and put it over in my source

Comment: @Someone: If you use the updated version of the function then no.

Comment: @Saul :Updated version of which function one stringify(). I dont have any

Comment: @Someone: Take a look at the answer. It contains a function called stringify(). You can use that one.

Comment: @Saul :Is this your written  custom Function or taken from Json.org

Comment: @Someone: It's taken from JSON.org.

Answer (score 1):

ok so here is what you can do.
I created an example to show you how it works.
It is actualy not using the serializeArray, but the JSON object:

/////
if using IE6, you will have to include the following js file into the header of your html document : https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
/////

// JAVASCRIPT 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var names = ["John", "Mike", "Joe"];
    var positions = ["flash", "php", "javascript"];

```
var arr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++){
    arr.push({"firstname": names[i], "position": positions[i] });
};

var json = JSON.stringify(arr);

$.ajax({
  url: "data.php",
  method:"GET",
  data: "json="+json,
   success: function(data){alert("data: "+data);},
  dataType: "text"
});
```

});

// DATA.PHP
$decoded = json_decode($_GET['json']);
echo $decoded[0]->firstname;

that works!

Comment: when i say checkedlines[m].serializeArray(); it is giving me error "Saying object doesnot support this property or method .And i also said  var items = checkedlines.serializeArray(); It is alos giving the same error